# MaximalBy in case of missing column entries

Tags: dataset, sorting

I have a large dataset, resulting from a `JoinAcross` operation, which looks similar like this one (only more complicated)

```
ds = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "B"} -> #] &]@{
      {"C09", 120},
      {"C09", 135},
      {"C09", 95},
      {"C10", 12},
      {"C10", Missing["Unmatched"]},
      {"C10", 150}}
```

[image: ds]

I want to perform `[GroupBy[#"ID" &] /* Values, MaximalBy[#"B" &] /* First]` and get the maximal numeric values for all IDs. But in case of C10 I get "Missing" as result of `MaximalBy`. The desired result would be 150.

If I'm using `MinimalBy` the problem is not occurring, seems that the `Missing["Unmatched"]` is sorted "above" the numerical values.

Any idea how to solve this problem, without changing the `Missing["Unmatched"]` into a zero or negative number?

Comment: Did you try changing the `MissingBehavior` of the query?

Comment: `MaximalBy[#"B" &]@(DeleteMissing/@ds)`?

Comment: @sebhofer I was'nt even aware of this option and didn't find out the right way to change it for my needs yet. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: @kglr couldn't get this to work, but I used WReach's suggestion with the replacement during the query, which is a quite similar idea, right?

Comment: I realize now that this wasn't a very useful suggestion, I mixed it up with `FailureBehavior`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use [TakeLargestBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeLargestBy.html) instead of `MaximalBy`:

```
ds[GroupBy["ID"] /* Values, TakeLargestBy["B", 1] /* First]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

`TakeLargestBy` has an `ExcludedForm` option which allows us to ignore expressions which match a certain pattern.  The default pattern excludes various null-like values including, conveniently, `Missing`.

**Value Replacement**

The question expressly excludes solutions involving value replacement, but I will point out that such replacement can be done fairly succinctly within the query itself.  For example:

```
ds[GroupBy["ID"] /* Values, MaximalBy[Replace[#B, _Missing -> 0] &]]
```

Such value replacement can be a very useful strategy in many types of queries.

**Canonical Order "Gotcha"**

In the present context, one might be tempted to use `-Infinity` as the replacement value for `Missing`.  However, this will not work because the various sorting and ordering functions in *Mathematica* (including `MaximalBy`) use so-called "canonical order".  This order has an unintuitive treatment for negative infinity:

```
MaximalBy[{1, 2, 3, -Infinity}, Identity]

(* -Infinity *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The `TakeLargestBy` is a very good idea and works perfectly for my example, but it doesn't work for a more complicated dataset, where also IDs with only a "Unmatched" line exist.

Comment: But - as always - you gave me even more hints and your proposal of the replacement in the query itself suits my application very well.